# change a attr of element when windows width less than value with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I want when windows width less than 992, change css attr of one element. I wrote this code:

```
$(document).ready()
{
    if ($(window).width() < 992) {
        $('#header_right').css('text-align', 'center');
    }
}
```

If I execute

```
if ($(window).width() < 992) {
    $('#header_right').css('text-align', 'center');
}
```

in console by ff done but when use this code in file such as up don't worked.

I use this js file in head:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Please advice.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: yes .Any error. This run currently

Comment: Can you use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries)?

Comment: Also your code does not run in `jQuery.ready()`. It runs after the call to `ready`, which is most likely before the document is ready.

Comment: Andreas  : Yes   I can

Comment: @programmer138200 Then use them from my answer. `:)`

Comment: @programmer138200 Lemme know if it works. `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is better solved by `@media` queries. You need to add this in your CSS:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 992) {
  #header_right {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

And you must bind this with the `window`'s `resize` event, **inside the `document`'s `ready` function**. Actually you have a syntax error there:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 992) {
      $('#header_right').css('text-align', 'center');
    }
  });
});
```

Because the current code you have, checks only once when the document is loaded and not every time when the window is resized.

Comment: OK. The css code don't worked .but js codes worked currently . Thank you It solved.